# Issues with conflicting IPs

Tags: wifi, infrastructure

Suppose there is a simple infrastructure wireless network. Suppose we have figured out a way for all clients on the network to coexist with all of them having the same IP address. What could be issues with such a setup (with regards to accessing a webserver located on the same network, accessing a webserver located on the internet, etc.)? Assume the clients are all using a single IP address that is different from the one used by the router, the webserver on the network, etc.

I have thought of some of the problems myself, and I'll post as comments possible solutions to those problems as people point them out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All these strange network questions you've posted the last few days make me wonder:

1. What are you really after?
2. What are you trying to accomplish?
3. Are these questions theoretical in nature or are you really trying to build a frankenstein network?

Comment: This almost sounds like a system to enable man-in-the-middle attacks on other wireless users, or spoofing other users.

Comment: muuuaahhaaaahaha!! My monster will be complete soon!! Just kidding...I would tell you what I'm trying o build, but I guess that would make this a discussion and not a QA session.

Answer (score 1):

How is your router going to maintain a NAT state table when all the clients are using the same IP?

How will you troubleshoot network issues when all the clients have the same IP?

Why in the world would you want to do this? Look into RFC1918 - those address ranges were created for a reason.

Comment: Not to mention that network communication would probably not occur at all due to the fact that the ip address could not be resolved to a single MAC address. Essentially every host would respond to the ARP request for that ip address.

Comment: Agreed - I guess I was trying to give him the benefit of the doubt that he, as stated, "figured out a way for all clients on the network to coexist with all of them having the same IP address".

Comment: I'd like to see this network once it's all put together. ;)

Answer (score 1):

For local connections, there is exactly one problem: you need to hack ARP. If you can do it, it will work regardless of application. Web server or mail server or foo server or even bar server.

For connections outside the local subnet, see the comment above regarding NAT.

Though, in my personal opinion, you should find something more productive to think about.